# when i access date in database using partition.it shows error

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL code and **mysql version 5.5**

```
SELECT * FROM employees1 PARTITION(p201701);
```

**error:**

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(p201701)' at line 1
>
> Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
>
> Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
>
> Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM employees1 PARTITION (p201701);
```

Add a whitespace after PARTITION

**EDIT:** this syntax works only on MySQL 5.6+. Your server is MySQL 5.5, that's why it doesn't work